# Associating variable with specific for loop file

Tags: bash, variable

I want to use `for` for a set of files.

```
for file in fileA fileB fileC; do
    COMMAND $file $variable
done
```

For every `$file` I want to use specific `$variable`.
(for example: fileA variableA; fileB variableB)

How can do such association?

Comment: what version of `bash`?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: `if [$ID="fileA"]` results in `command not found` here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare -A filevars
filevars[fileA]=foo
filevars[fileB]=bar
filevars[fileC]=baz
for file in fileA fileB fileC; do
  echo cmd "$file" "${filevars[$file]}"
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to associate multiple variables? `varA1 varA2 ` for fileA, etc?

Comment: @Poe Not directly, bash arrays are one-dimensional. But you can create arrays: arrayindex=0; filevarno[fileA]=$arrayindex; eval filevars_$arrayindex=(varA1 varA2); ((arrayindex++)); ...

Answer (score 3):

Since you are on v4 of `bash`, [associative arrays](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays) are an option

```
declare -A arr
arr=([fileA]=variableA [fileB]=variableB [fileC]=variableC)
for file in "${!arr[@]}"
 do
    command "$file" "${arr[$(basename $file)]}"
done
```

Note that order of processing may be different from the order within the array definition